# How can I use rowIndex of p:dataTable to hide/show another component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying out with p:dataTable. There I have three column. In second column I have commandbutton which when clicked, it should show inputbox on respective row in 3rd column. Inputbox on 3rd column has been set style="display:none"

MY xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="name" value="#{model.namelist}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{name} -----"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
                <p:commandButton value="click" onclick="som_#{rowIndex}.show();"></p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
        <p:inputText widgetVar="som_#{rowIndex}" style="display:none">
                </p:inputText>                  
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

I think it should work, but I dont know where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I run your code I got error in js like `som_0.show` is not a function. <strike>I guess widgetVar doesn't support el. That's why your code doesn't work</strike>. But this should solve your issue:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="name" value="#{model.nameList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{name} -----"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="click" onclick="$('.som_#{rowIndex}').show();"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:inputText styleClass="som_#{rowIndex}" style="display:none"/>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

As `styleClass` supports `el`. So I did the same thing with `styleClass` and with a little jQuery.

### Edit:

You probably need to add somewhere in your code the following line:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```

### Edit:

Here is you dynamic `widgetVar` version:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="name" value="#{so15320268.nameList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" widgetVar="table">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{name} -----"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="click" onclick="textVar_#{rowIndex}.getJQ().show();"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:inputText styleClass="som_#{rowIndex}" widgetVar="textVar_#{rowIndex}" style="display:none"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>                                  
</h:form>
```

After digging into the js source of primefaces I came to know that there is no `show` method in `PrimeFaces.widget.InputText` like `PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog`. So you need to extract the jQuery object behind from the `widgetVar` and it can be done by `widgetVar.getJQ()` or `widgetVar.jq`; these two has been defined in `PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget` as:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget = Class.extend({

    init: function(cfg) {
        this.cfg = cfg;
        this.id = cfg.id;
        this.jqId = PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(this.id),
        this.jq = $(this.jqId);

        //remove script tag
        $(this.jqId + '_s').remove();
    },

    //used mostly in ajax updates, reloads the widget configuration
    refresh: function(cfg) {
        return this.init(cfg);
    },

    //returns jquery object representing the main dom element related to the widget
    getJQ: function(){
        return this.jq;
    }

});
```

I have strikeout my previous comment as it is wrong. `widgetVar` does support el. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah this solved my issue. But I have 1 query, why el is not supported for widgetVar when it works for many attributes?

Comment: @KushSahu see my updated answer. And if your issue has been resolved then mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @TapasDas wowww... You searched it.. I am very beginner developer. I couldn't have find these. Thanks a lot. As you have such good knowledge can you suggest me how can I improve my skills. Thank you for your such brief explanation. :)

Comment: @KushSahu, you are welcome. I am also not a very experienced one :-). I just try to do code everyday. Try to look into code written by others. These help me a lot everyday. And I am Tapas Bose, in your last comment I became Tapas Das :-)

Comment: Sorry for that mistake and thank you very much for your suggestions. :)